# Multiple counters in a same page to count the time of each user.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to create multiple counters but not get done...
I have 4 states for every user in my page and I want to count time invested by the user in a single state..All the states are changed by user ..when users change their state the counter(up)
...start and reset again and count up to the next status change....
kindly help me as soon as imposable...

I had try many code but nor get done because the user are many and the counter code is one and the variable is one for each counter....the no of user are ..dynamic...

Comment: Can you supply the code you have tried, we might be able to show you where you are going wrong.

Comment: the last sentence makes me hope that there's a chance to help you, but we really need to see your code or we can't help you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if your trying the same in web application where multiple users are logging then surely it will get wanish .. for that you need to maintain the session for each counter (if possible).

or one suggestion will be at a time of click call callback(jquery/ ajax) which will start the counter and automatically it will get reset . but yes you need to maintain that as per session wise.

Comment: ok.....i have a counter which is working and but wher the page reload the counting lost of that particular counter ...so what should i do to set the counting again the same...

Comment: use $.cookie("key", value)  to maintaining counter tick.

Answer (score 0):

then there will be a one way to maintain that counter value in session for that user and on page load you can again start with the same count.

Answer (score 0):

Here i would suggest you to do that using Cookies by maintaining the counter value at client side.

You can use $.cookie("key", value) to set the value, and $.cookie("key") to get the saved value.

Also refer the article on jquery cookies.  http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/